# How to use context.Context with tcp connection read

Tags: go, networking

I am trying to create an intermediate layer between user and tcp, with `Send` and `Receive` functions. Currently, I am trying to integrate a context, so that the `Send` and `Receive` respects a context. However, I don't know how to make them respect the context's cancellation.
Until now, I got the following.

```
// c.underlying is a net.Conn

func (c *tcpConn) Receive(ctx context.Context) ([]byte, error) {
    if deadline, ok := ctx.Deadline(); ok {
        // Set the read deadline on the underlying connection according to the
        // given context. This read deadline applies to the whole function, so
        // we only set it once here. On the next read-call, it will be set
        // again, or will be reset in the else block, to not keep an old
        // deadline.
        c.underlying.SetReadDeadline(deadline)
    } else {
        c.underlying.SetReadDeadline(time.Time{}) // remove the read deadline
    }

    // perform reads with
    // c.underlying.Read(myBuffer)

    return frameData, nil
}
```

However, as far as I understand that code, this only respects a `context.WithTimeout` or `context.WithDeadline`, and not a `context.WithCancel`.
If possible, I would like to pass that into the connection somehow, or actually abort the reading process.

How can I do that?

Note: If possible, I would like to avoid another function that reads in another goroutine and pushed a result back on a channel, because then, when calling `cancel`, and I am reading 2GB over the network, that doesn't actually cancel the read, and the resources are still used. If not possible in another way however, I would like to know if there is a better way of doing that than a function with two channels, one for a `[]byte` result and one for an `error`.

**EDIT:**
With the following code, I can respect a cancel, but it doesn't abort the read.

```
    // apply deadline ...

    result := make(chan interface{})
    defer close(result)
    go c.receiveAsync(result)
    select {
    case res := <-result:
        if err, ok := res.(error); ok {
            return nil, err
        }
        return res.([]byte), nil
    case <-ctx.Done():
        return nil, ErrTimeout
    }
}

func (c *tcpConn) receiveAsync(result chan interface{}) {
    // perform the reads and push either an error or the
    // read bytes to the result channel
```

Comment: You should not be reading 2GB in a single Read call, there must be buffering in there. You should be able to check the cancelation going into each Read call rather than adding significant overhead for each Read.

Comment: It is not meant to be reading that much, but reading a few bytes over a really slow network can also be a pain. One call to `Receive` also performs multiple reads, but every single one of them can run for a while, can't it? Is there a way to abort the read?

Comment: I see, it's slow reads you're concerned about cancelling. I'll add an example.

Answer (score 1):

If the connection can be closed on cancellation, you can setup a goroutine to shutdown the connection on cancellation within the `Receive` method. If the connection must be reused again later, then there is no way to cancel a `Read` in progress.

```
recvDone := make(chan struct{})
defer close(recvDone)
// setup the cancellation to abort reads in process
go func() {
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        c.underlying.CloseRead()
        // Close() can be used if this isn't necessarily a TCP connection
    case <-recvDone:
    }
}()
```

It will be a little more work if you want to communicate the cancelation error back, but the `CloseRead` will provide a clean way to stop any pending TCP `Read` calls.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've added to the question that `c.underlying` is a `net.Conn`, which doesn't have a `CloseRead`(?) How would I implement that `CloseRead`?

Comment: Nevermind, I've just never heard of it. Since I am exclusively working with TCP connections, this should work. Let me check, then accept your answer!

Comment: @TimSatke: you can call `Close()` directly on a `net.Conn` too; it's just a little messier because you get a "use of closed connection" error to deal with.

Comment: Yeah that's what I just found out, it permanently closes my connection, making it unable to read or write again, correct?

Comment: `CloseRead`, as the docs state, closes only the read side of the connection. It's very rare that this is what you actually want. It also makes no guarantees that it will abort a `Read` call that's in progress.

Comment: @Adrian: `CloseRead` specifically will stop the `Read` call, because it calls the underlying shutdown read syscall.

Comment: @JimB on all current and future OSes on all Go versions? That doesn't seem like a promise you can make since the documentation doesn't mention it.

Comment: @Adrian: a lot of the network code assumes knowledge of the underlying berkely socket API (UDP for example has a lot of edges that are not documented because the basics of UDP should be understood), there would be no point to a `CloseRead` call on a TCP socket if it didn't shutdown the read on the TCP socket.

Comment: Presumably the point of `CloseRead` is what it says in the docs, to close only the read side of the connection. Regardless, it doesn't appear OP wants to close the connection at all, only to abort a read.

Comment: @Adrian: now that is a good point! If the connection needs to be used again this won't work ;)